# Is there an ability to use wildcards (*) in the query parameters with the BOSS API?

Tags: asp.net, web, yahoo-boss-api

I'm having trouble finding a definitive answer in the API documentation, or anywhere else online. Does anyone know if it's possible to include wildcards in the query parameters (either encoded or unencoded) when sending up a search web request? For example, "Corp*" would match both "Corp" and "Corporation".

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

For those who find this question some time in the future, the answer I received from their support team is below:

*With BOSS API, developers can fetch search content for Web, News, and Image results. At this point there is no option to use the wildcards in the search query to replace words in a query string.*

*I will surely forward this suggestion to our engineering team to see if this feature can be incorporated in our future release.*

So unfortunately there is no support as of May 20, 2015. Perhaps it will be added in the future.